# How to convert a user defined type to primitive type?

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a class called `Complex` which represents a complex number.
I want to convert this object to a `double` object.

The other way around i can do by implementing a copy ctor in Complex:
`Complex(const double &d);`

However, i can't implement i copy ctor in double which will receive a Complex.

How do i do this? I know there is a way with operator overloading, but i couldn't find how.
Eventually i want the this line will compile:
`Complex c;`
`(double)c;`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Implement a conversion operator on your Complex class:

```
class Complex
{
 // ...
  operator double() const
  { 
    double ret = // magic happens here
    return ret;
  }
};
```

If for whatever reason you don't want to muck about with this, you can provide a global conversion function:

```
double convert_to_double(const Complex& rhs)
{ 
  double ret = // magic happens
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The proper way of doing this is adding a conversion operator to your class.

```
class myclass {    
public:    
    operator double() const
    {
        return _mydouble;
    }
...
};
```

and used like this:

```
myclass c;
double d = c; // invokes operator double
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean you want to do this

```
Complex c;
double d =  c; ?
```

You can write a [conversion operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr385.htm) for that purpose

```
struct Complex{
   double double_val;

   operator double() const {
       return double_val;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The rub with a `Complex` class is that complex numbers are a superset of real numbers, i.e. while all real numbers are also complex numbers, not all complex numbers are real numbers.

So while, as others pointed out, you need to define a typecast operator in `Complex` for `double`, the real work is what you put into that function.  The safest thing would be to throw an exception if the number isn't real:

```
#include <exception>

struct Complex
{
    double real;
    double imag;

    Complex(double real_, double imag_ = 0.0): real(real_), imag(imag_) {)

    // ...

    class not_real: public exception
    {
        virtual const char* what() const throw()
        {
            return "cannot cast non-real complex number to double";
        }
    };

    operator double() const {
        if(imag != 0.0)
            throw not_real();
        return real;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

operator double is what you need

```
class Complex
{
   operator double() const {....}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cast operator:
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx
- Operator-Overloading/doublecastoperator.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200_Operator-Overloading/doublecastoperator.htm

So your code would look something like this (within your Complex class):
operator double () { return /* whatever you want to do to the complex */ }